# Ext window definition

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am a newbie to extjs - and see a Ext 'window' definition as follows in extJs 3.4:

```
var cfWin = new Ext.Window({
    id:'idNYC', 
    el:'NYC',
    .........
    contentEl:'NYCData',
    title:'NYC Data',
    ........
    });
```

While I do understand what 'id' would do;why would we need the el and contentel for?
When we have a index.html that loads the above script,do we need a div of the same name(id/el) in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official ExtJS documentation,

`Specify an existing HTML element, or the id of an existing HTML element to use as the content for this component.`

This means that if you have a `div` somewhere in your `index.html`, let say:

```
<div id="datalist">
    <ul>
        <li>Data 1</li>
        <li>Data 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And you specify `datalist` in `contentEl`, those html content will appear on your `Window`.

You can also specify the html directly:

`contentEl: "<h1>This is my content</h1>"`.

You cannot specify the `el` as it is a read-only property.

Comment: Why and when would we need  to specify el then?